Stuck on the induction step in a proof for $(x+\frac{1}{x})^n$
Background
I was playing around with the function $y=x+\frac{1}{x}$ and noticed the following pattern:
$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=y^2-2$
$x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=y^3-3y$
The issue
I am trying to prove $x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}=y^n-n\times y^{n-2}$ for natural numbers $n$.
Showing this is true for $n=1$ is easy, so I decided proof by induction proof may be the way to go.
Showing $n=k+1$ is implied by $n=k$ is giving me trouble and I suspect either my idea is wrong or there is an algebraic trick that I have missed.
Expressing $x^{k+1}+\frac{1}{x^{k+1}}$ in terms of $x^k+\frac{1}{x^k}$ was my first idea which leads to
$(x+\frac{1}{x})(x^k+\frac{1}{x^k})=x^{k+1}+\frac{1}{x^{k+1}}+x^{k-1}+\frac{1}{x^{k-1}}$
but that doesn't seem to be going anywhere.
Any and all ideas are welcome.
Edit (23/May)
Thanks for all the comments - the counter-example(s) have verified my suspicions that my formula was wrong. Much appreciated - thanks to all.

$n=1,4,5…$ are counter-examples

Your expression fails for $x=1$ on $n=4$. Left side is always 2 at $x=1$, the right side is $2^4-4\cdot 2^2 = 0$.

Are you familiar with the binomial theorem?  Pascal's triangle?  Both say that $(A+B)^4 = A^4\ +\ 4A^3B\ +6A^2B^2 + 4AB^3 + B^4$.  The first and the last terms will match the pattern, $4y^2= 4(x + \frac1x)^2$, matches the middle terms.
However, at first glance the pattern for the middle term breaks down at $6x^3 (1/x)^3)=6 \neq 8=4 * 2$

Thanks @RandyMarsh - I had a suspicion it wasn't going to work. Thanks heaps for verifying. If you want to add this as an answer I can accept it.

Thanks @nickalh - yes I was thinking about the binomial theorem a lot but couldn't find a way to work it into the proof. As you and others have now (thankfully) shown me, it is because the rule simply does not work. Much appreciated.

An old answer of mine contains a correct recurrence formula. Take a look! It is based on your last equation, but it is a two-step recurrence.

Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen - I am very interested in this so will do.

Oh, I should have started with the proper buzzword. You want to learn about Dickson polynomials. Particularly with the parameter $\alpha=1$. That WP page (and the links in there) give you a better thought out account of them than my old answer (tailored for a particular need).

The proposed equality does not hold for all $x$. For $x=1$, $y$ evaluates to $2$. Therefore, at $x=1$ the proposed equality is $2 = 2^{n-2}(4-n)$. Clearly for $n\geq 4$ the right-hand-side is less than or equal to $0$.
